# Liquibase can't create tables : ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

Tags: oracle, liquibase

Liquibase can actually create some of tables like DATABASECHANGELOG but it couldn't create rest of tables . I can create tables in my database with  same user but Liquibase just doesn't have priviligies to create all main tables.

Do you have any idea ? How can i fix this problem ?

I granted "create any table" priviliges to my user already but it doesn't fix my problem .

Comment: I guess even so you seemingly have done everything on the Oracle side this is still an Oracle privileges problem. What you can try to do is: Let liquibase not run the SQLs on the DB directly but write it to a file with `updateSQL`. Then try to run the exact same SQLs that liquibase wants to run on your DB. If you use the same credentials for the Oracle DB this should also result to the same error message.

Comment: can u try to run liquibase with the same username which you use when you are trying to create the table and paste the response ? i think the user which is used in liquibase and the user which you are using to create tables are different ? can you confirm ?